# Apache PDFBox cannot find class 'Loader'. Why?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using either **pdfbox-app-2.0.18.jar** or **pdfbox-app-2.0.17.jar**.

From the example [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java?view=markup&sortby=date), I have this code below :

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);
     PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(inputFile)) {
    
     // code

}
```

After executing this code, I'm getting this error given below :

```
org.apache.pdfbox.Loader is not found
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: You use an example from the svn trunk as you can see in its path. The trunk is the development version towards 3.0.0. For examples designed for a 2.0.18 release version, use examples from the svn branch/folder with the matching name.

Comment: @Anish in your edit you replaced the link given by the op by a shortened version of the code. While indeed one should include the relevant code in one's question, the url where one found it can be of help, too, see my previous comment. Thus, the link should remain alongside the shortened code.

Comment: @mkl I don't think that link is necessary for this problem. So, according to me, it should be removed. But if you still think it's necessary, then you can edit it.

Comment: As the original questioner, I agree with @mkl that the link was helpful and should be put back.

Comment: I edited the link back in. As the original questioner you also can always edit your post, by the way. There is an [edit] link right under your post.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I appreciate I can edit my own posts, I was waiting for Anish B to edit it back in, no worries and thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Loader class has been added January 25, 2020. [SVN log](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/Loader.java?view=log)

It's not part of version 2.0.18, as it is not in this file:
[pdfbox-2.0.18-src.zip](https://downloads.apache.org/pdfbox/2.0.18/pdfbox-2.0.18-src.zip)

So this class is simply too new and that's why you cannot use it!

Answer (score 11):

`Loader` class is never introduced in version 2.x or lower. So, you can't use it.

Alternatively, you can use `load()` method from `PDDocument` class to load PDF files.

Modify to this :

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);
     PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputFile)) {

        // code 

}
```

Read this :- https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html

Comment: Your suggestion should work..however it doesn't answer the specific problem of why this class cannot be found. Also why is the example using Loader.loadPDF(inputFile)) if PDDocument.load(inputFile)) is the same?

Comment: @user2677034 I tried to find in lower jars also, but it's missing. I'm not finding it.

Comment: @Anish I don't understand your recent edit: *"I think the Loader class is removed from version 2.x and that's why you are facing that issue"* - as has been explained in other comments and answers, it's not *removed* from 2.x, it has never been in 1.x or 2.x versions! It is material from the upcoming 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

The `PDDocument` class will represent the PDF document that is being processed. Its `load()` method will load in the PDF file specified by the File object :

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("path/to/pdf"));
```